# Changing web to https

Tags: https, firewall, ports, windows-firewall

I am trying to change my site to https (port 443). Everything works correctly except for one thing, on my site i'm using a service call Yawcam which allows to stream a webcam (I'm using port 8081 to that end).

It is working when I use for my Apache server port 80 (http://myip:8081), but when using port 443 it doesn't respond (https://myip:8081).

All ports mentioned are opened to Public (80,443,8081) through my Windows Server firewall.

I'm out of ideas, do you have any?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with your firewall, this is to do with the fact that you are using mixed content. 
Chances are you are using http:// for the external service and this will be blocked by browsers as they do not like it when you try to load a less secure resource than the loaded page.
Try changing your external content URLs to https:// if possible.
You can see here for a little more info on what you could try: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content